# Rename pandas dataframe based on nested dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, rename

I have a dictionary:

```
groupings = {'Group_A':{'species':['plantain', 'banana'], 'shape':'oblong'},
'Group_B':{'species':['lemon', 'orange'], 'shape':'round'}
}
```

I also have a dataframe:

```
d = pd.dataframe(data={'orange': [1, 2], 'bannana': [3, 4], 'lemon': [3, 4]})
```

I would like to rename and sum the data frame based on the dictionary:

```
#something like this:
d.rename(columns=groupings, inplace=True)
d = d.groupby(by=d.columns, axis=1).sum()
```

Expected output:

```
Group_A  Group_B
3          4
4          6
```

How do I reshape the dictionary so it is recognized by pandas.DataFrame.rename()?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dictionary comprehension to flatten the value of `species`

```py
d = {species:k
    for k, v in groupings.items()
    for species in v['species']}

out = (df.rename(columns=d)
       .groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum())
```

```
$ print(d)

{'plantain': 'Group_A', 'banana': 'Group_A', 'lemon': 'Group_B', 'orange': 'Group_B'}


$ print(out)

   Group_A  Group_B
0        3        4
1        4        6
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a mapping of the column names in the dataframe to the desired column names specified in the dictionary:

```
groupings = {
    'Group_A': {'species': ['plantain', 'banana'], 'shape': 'oblong'},
    'Group_B': {'species': ['lemon', 'orange'], 'shape': 'round'}
}

d = pd.DataFrame(data={'orange': [1, 2], 'bannana': [3, 4], 'lemon': [3, 4]})

column_mapping = {}
for group, attributes in groupings.items():
    species_list = attributes['species']
    for species in species_list:
        column_mapping[species] = group

d.rename(columns=column_mapping, inplace=True)
d = d.groupby(by=d.columns, axis=1).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

This should work for the instance that multiple groups have the same species.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({k1:df.reindex(v1.get('species'),axis=1).sum(axis=1) for k1,v1 in groupings.items()}).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
   Group_A  Group_B
0        3        4
1        4        6
```